# Как дождаться отрабатывания колбека асинхронного метода?

Tags: java, асинхронность

Есть метод, реализованный в сторонней библиотеке, у которого есть 2 коллбека: на успех и на ошибку.
Сейчас я весь код, который должен выполняться после успешного завершения этих методов, пихаю в колбек, получается огромная матрёшка. Но сейчас возникла проблема:

```
if (flag){
  pc.method(p1, p2, new ICallback() {
    @Override
      public void error(IError error) {
      String errMsg = "Ошибка: " + error.getMessage();
      Log.e(TAG, errMsg);
    }

    @Override
      public void success() {
      Log.i(TAG, "Успех");
    }
  });
}
else{
  // Код, который выполняется только после успеха, если flag == true, и всегда, когда flag == false
}
```

Требуется этот метод pc.method вызвать синхронно. Дальше идёт код, который выполняется только тогда, когда метод выполнился успешно (сработал колбек на успех), либо (flag == false). Как делаю сейчас - мне придётся продублировать огромный кусок кода: внутри колбека и после if'а. Разработчики библиотеки говорят, что необходимо дождаться результата, потом только выполнять код в зависимости от того, успех или нет. Аналогов нет, использовать надо только её.

Также есть ещё один метод, у него в "успешный" колбек передаётся массив объектов, который надо будет использовать ПОСЛЕ выполнения этого метода. Сейчас я всё делаю внутри колбека. Хотелось бы результат вынести в вызывающий метод.

Comment: Так а в чем проблеиа сделать внешний метод в этом же классе и вызыватьего?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно остановить выполнение метода, дождаться результата и потом продолжить? Вот тут я делал нечто похожее. флаг блокировки и остановка в синхронизируемом блоке
https://github.com/MaximKulikov/Java-GoodGame-Api-Wrapper/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/maximkulikov/goodgame/api/realization/PlayerRealization.java

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, правильно ли понял вопрос...

```
boolean done = false;
Object lock = new Object();

pc.method(p1, p2, new ICallback() {
    @Override
    public void error(IError error) {
        String errMsg = "Ошибка: " + error.getMessage();
        Log.e(TAG, errMsg);

        // разбудить ожидающий поток
        synchronized(lock) {
            done = true;
            lock.notify();
        }
    }

    // Аналогично success
    ...
);

// ждать завершения работы pc.method, точнее одного из callback-ов
synchronized (lock) {
    if (!done) {
        lock.wait();
    }
}

// Код, который выполняется только после успеха, если flag == true, и всегда, когда flag == false
...
```

`done` используется на тот случай, если `notify` сработает раньше `wait`-а.

Если `notify` сработает раньше, то `wait` никогда не получит сигнал и уснёт навсегда.
Но `done` к этому времени будет установлен в `true` и условие обойдёт `wait`, когда он рискует уснуть навсегда.

Может Вам нужны promise? Тем более когда результаты предыдущего шага являются входными параметрами следующего.
Вместо матрёшки можно получить последовательные блоки. В java (c 8 версии) для этого предлагается `CompletableFuture`

Comment: Переменные done и lock должны быть объявлены как final, т.к. используются в колбеках. Сделал следующим образом: 
  final boolean[] done = {false};
  final Object lock = new Object(); 
  Метод тот же самый, который предлагал в комментарии @Maxim. Если ошибка в отсутствии подключения - всё корректно обрабатывается. Если ошибка приходит с сервера - в колбек вообще не заходит. Но если убрать синхронизацию - колбек срабатывает.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, как метод `method` объекта `pc` можно преобразовать к `CompletableFuture`. Я не могу его переопределить, и обязан реализовать именно эти коллбеки. А так - да, это был бы идеальный вариант.

Comment: Может есть такие ошибки, которые pc.method не перенаправляет в callback по каким-то причинам. И при этом не кидается исключениями. Не хороший какой-то метод.

Comment: Я уже написал разработчикам библиотеки. Как придёт ответ - сообщу.

Comment: И ещё, колбек отрабатывает в любом случае, если убрать весь код, отвечающий за синхронизацию.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге сделал, как посоветовал @GenCloud, вынес код, который идёт после этого странного коллбека, в отдельный метод и вызываю его из коллбека и из else'а. Почему коллбек не срабатывал, когда добавлял синхронизацию - так и не понял. Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь объяснит это поведение java.